# Performing arithmetic on char in c

Tags: c

I am learning C and was looking into the function strchr. I found the following code and it confuses me.

```
/* strchr example */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (){

char str[] = "This is a sample string";
char * pch;
printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
pch=strchr(str,'s');

while (pch!=NULL) {
   printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
   pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
}
return 0;
}
```

with the following output

```
Looking for the 's' character in "This is a sample string"...
found at 4
found at 7
found at 11
found at 18
```

variable pch and array str are both char, why is that when performing arithmetic on them, they become integer?  I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Removed the C++ tag because the C++ answer would be "Don't do that".

Comment: No. Performing arithmetic on a pointer means it does remain a pointer. Neither `pch` nor `str` are `char`, by the way.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Aw, come on, it's not like they're using strtok.

Comment: `pch` is a pointer `(unsigned int)` which holds a `char` type

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja No, `pch` is not  a pointer to `(unsigned int)`. If it was, the result printed from the program would not have been correct. Or, if you are trying to say a pointer is equivalent to an unsigned int, that isn't correct either. (E.G.  on my machine, a pointer is twice as big as an unsigned int.)

Comment: Your `printf` statement uses `%d` as its format specifier, which expects an `int` argument and outputs it in signed decimal notation. So it is no surprise that you get an integer in your output.

Comment: @mindriot I tried changing it to %c, but it's giving me the following  errorstructs_lists.c:25:5: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at the statement in question:

```
printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
```

In this arithmetic context, you are operating on *pointers* to `char`, so this is classic pointer arithmetic:

- `pch` is of type `char *`
- `str` is of type `char[]`, which decays into another `char *` pointer type
- `pch-str` is technically of type `ptrdiff_t`, an alias of a signed integer type (in your case `long int`)

So the complete expression, `pch-str+1`, is also of type `long int`.

Finally, your `printf` statement uses a `%d` format specifier, which expects an `int` argument and outputs it as a signed decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

No, they **do not become integers**.

It's possible to do maths on pointers as well as integers and floating-point numbers, so, if `char str[] = "hello";`, then `*(str+1)` is equal to 'e', and `*(str+N)` is the `N`th character after the first one.

Comment: Hi @ForceBru, when I tried to print char `printf ("found at %c\n",pch-str+1);` instead of integer I got the following error. `structs_lists.c:25:5: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]`. I'm still confused, why does it says argument 2 has type long int?

Comment: @user116064, that's because `pch-str+1` is a pointer that represents a memory address, and this address can be pretty huge, so it's stored in a type that can hold it (`size_t` -> `long int`). If you want to print the character it points to, you should enclose this in parentheses and add an asterisk in front of them (dereference a pointer): `*(pch-str+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that pch is a pointer. When you add a constant number to a pointer it is equivalent to an array. For eg. 
    `char *ptr`.
    `ptr[i]`is equivalent to `ptr+i` and is also equivalent to `i+ptr`. That is not the arithmatic on char variable but performing arithmetic operation on character pointer.

Make sure a pointer of any type is an integer that holds address.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic types of data type in C. That is integer type and float type. Character is also belongs to an integer type which is of One Byte Only (i.e) 8 Bits. So it can also store the integer value till 255. Because 2^8 = 256 (0-255).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing integer arithmetic you are doing the pointer arithmetic.
pch is a pointer and pch +1 means that pch + 1*sizeof(char). Here strchr is of the following type

```
char *strchr(const char *str, int c).
```

You can read more about strchr [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array of pointer p[] of any data type then p represents the address where p is pointing. So when we do p+1 the address is increased by one byte or 4 byte as according to p being a pointer to char or pointer to an integer.

In every case p is an address which essentially is an integer.

So when you do pch+1 pch is a memory address which is an integer.